# Parsing and retrieving values from XML using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

My Sample XML:

```
 <Group-1>
   <One>
     <two>Name1</two>
     <three>Type1</three>
   </One>
   <One>
     <two>Name2</two>
     <three>Type2</three>
   </One>
 </Group-1>
 <Group-2>
   <One-2></One-2>
 </Group-2>
```

There are two XML different XML Parent tags in my XML.
How can i retrieve the values from the above XML using XML parsers using core java?
I have seen examples using getelementsbytagname("").But i need some method to retrieve all the values when there are many repeats and also for simple XML tags?
Can anyone plz help me on this?

Comment: you could always just add <parent>...</parent> around it and then you have a valid, single parent xml

Comment: I need to parse a dynamically generated xml.It might have 2 repeats or 3 repeats,depending on the requirements

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `JAXBContext` marshall and unmarshall